# Proving a recurrence relation in up-down permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Let $f_n(q)$ be the generating function of the number of Zigzag permutations of size $n$ that start with an up-step, according to the inv statistic.
>   Prove that :

$$1. f_{n+1}(q)= \sum_{j=0,\dots, n\\ \text{$j$ odd}} \binom{n}{j}_q q^{n-j}f_j(q)f_{n-j}(q).$$
2.Find the q_exponential generating function of $f_n(q)$.

Here are some definitions we are using:

An *up-down permutation of size $n$ that starts with an up-step* means a permutation $\pi = \pi_1 \pi_2 \cdots \pi_n$ (written in one-line notation) with $\pi_1 < \pi_2 > \pi_3 < \pi_4 > \pi_5 \cdots \pi_n$.

For example, for $n=2$, the only such permutation is $\pi = 12$.

For $n=3$, the only two such permutations are $132$ and $231$.

The inv statistic sends a permutation $\pi$ to $\operatorname{inv}(\pi) := \left| \left\{ (i,j) \mid 1 \leq i < j \leq n,\  \pi_i > \pi_j \right\} \right|$.

For example, for $\pi = 1$, we have $\operatorname{inv}(\pi) = 0$.

For $\pi = 12$, we have $\operatorname{inv}(\pi) = 0$.
For $\pi = 21$, we have $\operatorname{inv}(\pi) = 1$.

Can someone suggest a clear solution to this question?
For 2 I substituted the $f_{n}(q)$ formula from the 1st part in : 
$f(x,q)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f_n(q) x^n}{[n]_q!}$ 
And I got:
$x*\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{q^{n-j-1}f_j(q) x^j f_{n-j-1} x^{n-j-1}}{[n]_q [j]_q! [n-j-1]_q!})$

Can someone help me in 2, i tried hard but I did not get a simplification to this.

Comment: I think splitting at the greatest element (or possibly least element) gives you the recursion. You also need (I seem to recall) that the number of up-down perms is the same as the number of down-up ones.

Comment: Do you have an idea for 2? @ancientmathematician

Comment: I would myself take the result (1), multiply it by $\frac{x^{n+1}}{(q;q)_{n+1}}$, and sum for all $n$. On the RHS I would split the $q$-choose into three, putting the right bits with $x^j f_j$ and $x^{n-j} f_{n-j}$; I'd pull out the extra $x$ and whatever constant is left and then see what I'd got. Is it that $f(x,q)$ [plus some constant]  equals something recognisable done to  $f(x,q)^2$?

Comment: I tried what you said but did not manage to simplify , or it was not enough clear for me. Can you explain the coming steps? @ancientmathematician

Comment: I haven't worked it out, sorry. Is this in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics? Has Knuth got something on this stuff? Have you looked through papers on combinatorial trigonometry? These are the places I'd go to next.

Comment: (ctd) There are many papers on " $q$-analogues of the secant numbers" and the like, which is what this is (I think).

Comment: It is just a topic in q-series /q-calculus (q-binom) , I don't know it it belongs to Stanley.., I did not find something beneficial to help me simplify it after I searched in many papers and articles...@ancientmathematician

Comment: I wonder if it is in "A Comprehensive Treatment of q-Calculus" by Thomas Ernst?

Comment: Can one mimic the usual proof for the case $q\to 1$? I'd split the GF into even terms $A(x)$ and odd terms $B(x)$ and then the recurrence leads at once to $A'=BA$ and $B'=A^{2}$ which lead at once to $A=sec, B=tan$. In the $q$ case are these true for a $q$-analogue of differentiation? Does it help? [But this is beyond my pay-grade.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician
I really don't know:/ i gave this question a lot of time but didn't succeed! and I'm now so curious about it , can u help me please

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it out. I was hoping some expert would answer this. Is this paper of Stanley any help: http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/altperm.pdf

Comment: @ancientmathematician thanks , yes in Stanley's pdf theory 2.1 page 6 (first theory) can be a probable solution i guess, but there is no proof to it!

Comment: one last remark. Is this not in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics, vol 1, page 148: formula (57) with $k=1$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I didn't find it here: www-math.mit.edu › ~rstanPDF
Enumerative Combinatorics Volume 1 second edition - MIT Mathematics

Comment: 2nd Edition after my time! But see 3.99 on page 373.

Comment: @ancientmathematician i looked at it , i did not find something special about it..the idea is how to siplify the last formula i wrote

Comment: I believe formula this gives the generating function you want (possibly you need to change $x$ to $xq$). You'd get a proof of some sort if you could show the coeffts in Stanley's formula satisfy the same recurrence as you've got.

Comment: @ancientmathematician The formula 3.99 is not known to me, that's why i can't guess how it can help. In my formula i have 1/[n]_q and two sum's which I have no idea how to simplify them

Comment: It looks like $F(x)=1/G(x)$ so re-express as $F(x)G(x)=1$; now see what recurrence relation that gives you. Does it let you check that the coeffts of F$ satisfy the the relation you start with? But seriously, I don't think I can help further - and would like to see an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Define the standard finite sets $\,[n]:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.\,$
   We need the definition from Wikipedia of an
   [inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)).
   For a function $\,s:[n]\to[m]\,$ an inversion is a pair $\,i<j\,$
   such that $\,s(i)>s(j).\,$
   Call an injective function $\,s\,$ "up-down" if $\,s(j)<s(j+1)\,$
   iff $\,j\,$ is odd. Important examples include the
   [alternating permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_permutation).

The Wikipedia article
   [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient)
   defines $\,[n]_q := 1+q+...+q^{n-1},\;$
   $\,[n]_q! := [1]_q[2]_q\cdots[n]_q,\;$ and
   $\,\binom{n}{m}_q := [n]_q!/([m]_q![n-m]_q!).\,$ The
   "Combinatorial description" section of the Wikipedia article
   gives an interpretation of "inversion" for "words". This is
   equivalent to the following interpretation. Each $m$-subset
   $\,A\,$ (a subset with $\,m\,$ elments) of $\,[n]\,$ is uniquely
   determined by $\textbf{1}_A$, its
   [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function).
   An inversion of $\,A\,$ is defined as an inversion of
   $\textbf{1}_A.$ That is, a pair $\,i<j\,$ where
   $\,i\in A\,$ and $\,j\in [n]\setminus A.\,$ In other words,
   $\textbf{1}_A(i)=1>\textbf{1}_A(j)=0.$ Every $m$-subset with
   $\,k\,$ inversions adds $\,q^k\,$ to the total sum
   $\,\binom{n}{m}_q.\,$ The Wikipedia article on Guassian binomial
   coefficient has more inversions details.

Given any up-down permutation $\,s\,$ on $\,[n\!+\!1]\,$ there is
   a unique number $\,j\in[n]\,$ such that $\,s(j\!+\!1)=n\!+\!1\,$
   since $\,s\,$ is a bijection and this $\,j\,$ can **not** be even
   since if $\,j\,$ is even then that would imply $\,s(j)>n\!+\!1\,$
   which is impossible. This splits the domain
   $\,[n\!+\!1]\,$ into three connected intervals as follows
   $$ [n\!+\!1]=[j]\cup\{j\!+\!1\}
   \cup\{j\!+\!2,\dots,n\!+\!1\}. \tag{1} $$
   Because $\,s\,$ is a bijection, the image is partitioned into three
   sets as follows
   $$ [n\!+\!1]=s([j])\cup\{n\!+\!1\}
   \cup s(\{j\!+\!2,\dots,n\!+\!1\}). \tag{2} $$
   The function $\,s\,$ restricted to the first domain
   is an up-down function, and restricted to the third domain is
   an up-down function since $\,1\,$ and $\,j\!+\!2\,$ are both odd.

The first image is a $j$-subset of $\,[n]\,$ and the third image is
   its complementary subset in $\,[n]\,$. The number of inversions
   of $\,s\,$ is the sum of the inversions contributed by the first
   and third images alone, then the inversions formed by the first
   and third images compared (included in $\,\binom{n}{j}_q\,$),
   and finally, the second image $\,\{n+1\}\,$ contributes $\,n-j\,$
   inversions since $\,n+1\,$ is greater than all of elements in the
   third image. All of this is combined into the equation
   $$ f_{n+1}(q) = \sum_{j\; \text{odd}}
      \binom{n}{j}_q q^{n-j}f_j(q)f_{n-j}(q) \tag{3}$$
   where $\,f_n(q)\,$ is defined to be the sum over all the up-down
   permutations $\,s\,$ on $\,[n]\,$ with each $\,s\,$ adding $q$
   raised to the number of inversions of $\,s\,$ to the sum.

Comment: First I was asked to Prove the recursion 1. Which was given in this question, second 2. I want to find the q-exponential generating function of $f_n(q)$ which is defined at the beginning of the question, so in order to find it (the q-exponential generating function) i'm supposed to substitute in this formula: $f(x,q)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f_n(q) x^n}{(q;q)_n}$ (i don't know another way to find it) , however I'm stuck after substituting....

Comment: it seems that i did not understand what you mean by souse of recursion....

Comment: Anyway, the PDF of Stanley, "A Survey of Alternating Permutations" near the bottom of page 2 is the ordinary analog of the recursion you are supposed to prove. It is a small step to find the q-analogue. The q-analog of $E_n$ is given by equation (2.3) on page 5. In page 6,  Theorem 2.1 is  the q-analog e.g.f. for $E_n(q)$ which is the natural q-analog of $\,\tan(x)+\sec(x)\,$ in terms of $\,\sin_q(x)\,$ and $\,\cos_q(x).$